# Converting from utf8 to hex and back with Javascript

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to encrypt text using WebCrypto. I convert the result to a utf8 string, then convert that to hex. The encryption/decryption works. However, I want to convert the data to hex. When I try to convert to hex and back, the result is different.

Here's the fiddle (use Chrome): https://jsfiddle.net/yxp01v5g/

The test code is here:

```
var text = "hello world";
var key = App.crypto.generateKey(16);

App.crypto.encrypt(text, key, function(encryptedText, iv){
  console.log("encrypted text:", encryptedText, "iv", iv);

  var encryptedTextHex = convertUtf8StringToHex(encryptedText);
  console.log("encrypted text hex", encryptedTextHex);

  var backToUtf8 = convertHexToUtf8(encryptedTextHex);
  console.log("Back to utf8", backToUtf8);
  console.assert(encryptedText == backToUtf8);
})
```

As you can see, I'm taking the result, converting it to hex, then converting it back to utf8, hoping for it to be equal to the original result. However, it's not.

Can anyone tell me what on earth I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't dig too deep into the call-chain used in the fiddle to do the conversion, but it appears to try converting UTF-16/UCS-2 to byte size instead of an actually hex representation of the buffer content itself.

Here is one approach to convert the byte buffer content to hex string representation, and from hex string back to binary data.

It takes each byte in the buffer and produced a two-digit hex representation of its value, and concatenates it to a string.

The reverse takes two chars from the string representation and converts it back to a byte value representation.

```js
// some bytes as Uint8Array
var random = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16)), i, str = "", allOK = true;

// convert to HEX string representation
for(i = 0; i < random.length; i++) str += pad2(random[i].toString(16));
console.log(str);

// convert back to byte buffer
var buffer = new Uint8Array(random.length);
for(i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) buffer[i] = parseInt(str.substr(i<<1, 2), 16);

// check if same content
for(i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) if (buffer[i] !== random[i]) allOK = false;
console.log("All OK?", allOK)

function pad2(s) {return s.length < 2 ? "0" + s : s}; // helper: pad to 2 digits
```